# What can I use to set cookies in Java?

Tags: java, cookies, nanohttpd

I am using a nanoHttp server. Nothing I have tried will work. I need to be able to click on one link (http://localhost:9090/createCookie) that calls a method to create a cookie for a different link (http://localhost:9090/application).

NanoHttp cookies do not support setting a path which is why I can't use them

Comment: Which "nanoHttp" server?

Comment: http://www.nanohttpd.org/index.html

Comment: Are you able to set headers? Because a cookie is sent to the browser in the form of a header with a particular name (Set-Cookie): https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/05/05/http-cookies-explained/.

Comment: I don't know but I will look into this, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`CookieHandler`](http://nanohttpd.org/nanohttpd/apidocs/fi/iki/elonen/NanoHTTPD.CookieHandler.html), from your `NanoHTTPD` instance:

```
@Override
public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
    // ...
    CookieHandler ch = new CookieHandler(session.getHeaders());
    ch.set("cookieName", "encoded cookie value", nDaysValid);
    // ...
    Response response = ...; // Build up response
    ch.unloadQueue(response); // Add cookies to it
    return response;
}
```

What do you mean by *NanoHttp cookies do not support setting a path*?

Comment: I found that you have to add the cookies to the response at the end of the serve() like this:  `Response response = newFixedLengthResponse(msg); ch.unloadQueue(response); return response;`